# problems with this singleton (Not class)

Tags: c++, templates, function, singleton

I am sure this could have been answered but I couldn't actually find a consolidated answer.

what are the problems with the following singleton that is just a function and guaranteed to have initialization and assuming T supports operator!, needed constructors, functions etc? (I am not looking for thread safety). More over, its ok for others to create objects of T as T in my case is a database handle I want to use for the life of my program.

```
template<typename T>
T* getInstance(){
    static T instance;
    if ( !instance && !instance.initialize() ){
       return NULL;
    }
    else {
       return &instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not thread safe... that's what's wrong.

Comment: The main problem with this is that you attempt to use a Singleton. Singleton is an anti-pattern. [Don't use it.](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code -- the template type is being used instead of the variable.

For what you need (don't care about thread safety & need it for the entire duration of your application), it might be exactly what you need. You might wish to start from this though:

```
template<typename T> T* getInstance()
{
    static T instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, edited the code to use properly. The problem for me is object construction may not necessarily initialize. However, I see your point in pushing it into the object construction itself

Answer (score 0):

This won't even compile. Moreover, using singletons will get you in trouble sooner or later. For instance, when will you destroy the instance? In C++ it is generally better to be explicit about construction and destruction. Lookup the [static gateway pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html) ([example in C#](http://codebetter.com/jpboodhoo/2007/10/15/the-static-gateway-pattern/)).

Good luck!

Comment: You don't have to manually destroy static instances in C++, they will be destroyed, in reverse construction order, after `main` ends.

Comment: Yes Fred that's right, and that is the problem. The destruction order depends on the construction order, of which you really have no control.